# Calculate power of the test $H_0$: $\sigma^2 \leq \sigma_0^2$ vs. $H_1$: $\sigma^2 > \sigma_0^2$ for $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ data.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. We consider the testing problem $H_0$: $\sigma^2 \leq \sigma_0^2$ vs. $H_1$: $\sigma^2 > \sigma_0^2$ and the statistical test $\delta:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ defined as follows:

$$\delta(x) = \begin{cases}
1 &\mbox{if } \ \frac{1}{\sigma_0^2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \geq \chi^{2-}_{n, \, 1 - \alpha}\\
0 &\mbox{else}
\end{cases}$$

where $\chi^{2-}_{n, \, 1 - \alpha}$ denotes the $1-\alpha$ quantile of the Chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom. (I've heard that this is the uniformly most powerful test for our situation, is that correct?).

We now want to calculate the power of this test. I.e., given $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$, we evaluate for $\sigma^2 \in (0, \infty)$:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{\sigma^2}(\delta(X)) &= \mathbb{P}_{\sigma^2}(\delta(X) = 1)\\
&= \mathbb{P}_{\sigma^2} \left( \frac{1}{\sigma_0^2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \geq \chi^{2-}_{n, \, 1 - \alpha} \right)\\
&= \mathbb{P}_{\sigma^2} \left( \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \geq \frac{\sigma_0^2}{\sigma^2}\chi^{2-}_{n, \, 1 - \alpha} \right)\\
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}_{\sigma^2} \left( \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \leq \frac{\sigma_0^2}{\sigma^2}\chi^{2-}_{n, \, 1 - \alpha} \right)
\end{align}

Note that $\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \right) \sim \chi^{2}_{n}$. Hence, when $\sigma^2 = \sigma_0^2$ we have
\begin{align}\mathbb{E}_{\sigma^2}(\delta(X)) &= 1 - \mathbb{P}_{\sigma^2} \left( \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \leq \chi^{2-}_{n, \, 1 - \alpha} \right)\\
&= 1 - (1 - \alpha)\\
&= \alpha
\end{align}

My question: can we explicitly calculate $\mathbb{E}_{\sigma^2}(\delta(X))$ when $\sigma^2 \neq \sigma_0^2$?

Comment: Are you asking for a closed-form expression of the power function? The power function as you have found can be written in terms of incomplete gamma function which is the cdf of $\chi^2_n$.  Power is evaluated at a specific value of $\sigma^2(\ne \sigma_0^2)$. So of course, given some actual value of $\sigma^2$, this probability can be calculated.

Comment: Are you looking for an exact value or an approximation? If the latter, you can use the fact that $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 $ is approximately $\mathcal{N}(n,2n)$

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes, I was looking for a closed form expression that wouldn't involve complicated gamma functions or such stuff. However, it makes sense to just use the cdf to calculate the values one is interested in. Thank you!

Comment: @MatthewH. this approximation looks interesting. Can you link some reference with further details?

Comment: This is just the central limit theorem.

Comment: @MatthewH. I see it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have verified
that when $H_0$ is true, the rejection rate of a
test at the 5% level is 0.05, as it should be.

Yes, it is possible to find the power of the test
for a particular alternative value of $\sigma_a^2.$
You can use an analytical method similar to what you did for
for the significance level when the null hypothesis
is true. (For *numerical* results you will need software or a suitable printed table of chi-squared distribution.)

I will show results from simulations. In many
power computations, simulation is necessary because
the distribution of the test statistic when $H_0$
is false is unknown or too messy to handle analytically. However, I hope you will see from
my simulations how to find the power analytically
for your question.

**One test with null hypothesis true.** With $H_0: \sigma^2 = 36$ true
tested against $H_a: \sigma^2 > 36$ at the 5% level, we do not reject because the P-value exceeds 5%.

For example, given a vector `x` of $n=100$ observations
from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 0, \sigma=6),$ the test would
look like this:

```
set.seed(114)
n = 100;  sg = 6        
x = rnorm(n, 0, sg)           # data
v = mean(x^2);  v             # variance est
[1] 37.91495
h = n*v/36;  h                # test stat
[1] 105.3193
pv = 1 - pchisq(h,100);  pv   # P-val of test
[1] 0.3384785                 # > 5%; don't rej
```

**Many tests.** With null hypothesis true, testing at level 5%, the P-value should be less than
5% in 5% of the tests.

```
set.seed(2022)
pv = replicate(10^5, 
       1-pchisq(sum(rnorm(100,0,6)^2)/36, 100))
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.05044         # aprx significance level
2*sd(pv <= .05)/sqrt(10^5)
[1] 0.001384143     # 95% margin of sim error
```

So, the significance level of the test is $0.0504 \pm 0.0014;$  essentially 5% as expected. (With 100,000
iterations we can expect about 2-place accuracy
for the result.)

Moreover, for an exact tests using a continuous-valued
test statistic, the distribution of P-values under $H_0$ is distributed $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ as
illustrated by the histogram below. Rejection
occurs only for the 5% of instances to the left of
the vertical red line.

```
hist(pv, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 abline(v = .05, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

**Many tests when the null hypothesis is false.**
By contrast, when $\sigma^2 = 64 > \sigma_0^2 = 36,$
the rejection rate is much higher. We repeat
the simulation above with the alternative value
$\sigma_a^2 = 64.$

```
set.seed(2022)
pv = replicate(10^5, 
       1-pchisq(sum(rnorm(100,0,8)^2)/36, 100))
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.99025    # aprx power of the test
```

The power of the test (rejection probability when
the null hypothesis is false in a particular way)
is about 99%.

Now, the distribution of the P-value is far from uniform.

```
hist(pv, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 abline(v = .05, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this comprehensible power simulation tutorial! Only thing I struggle with is the computation of the error margin of the significance level. Can you explain why this yields a 95% margin?

Comment: When $H_0$ is true, the probability of rejection is the margin of error (first simulation. $.05$ when $\sigma^2=6^2=36)$. When $H_0$ is false in a particular way, the probability of rejection is the power of the test for that particular alternative value of the parameter (second, $.99$ when $\sigma^2= 8^2=64)$.

Comment: Misunderstanding. I was referring to this line: `2*sd(pv <= .05)/sqrt(10^5)`. Why does this yield a confidence(?) margin?

Comment: That amounts to the margin of error in a 95% Wald confidence interval for the simulated P-value. (Using $2$ instead of $1.96.)$ // The Wald CI $\bar X \pm 1.96 S/\sqrt{n}$ has poor properties for small $n$ because it is intended as an asymptotic CI to be used for large $n.$ In simulations $n$ tends to be very large,

Comment: Additional note on vector types in R: `pv` is a numeric vector or 100,000 P-values. `pv <= .05` is a logical vector of 100,000 TRUEs and FALSEs. The `mean` of a logical vector is the proportion of its TRUEs (where FALSE counts as 0; TRUE counts as 1).

Comment: The Wald CI for the parameter $p$ of the Bernoulli distribution. Makes sense, thanks for your explanations!